# Php date function result is incorrect

Tags: php, datetime

Problem with Date function

output: 00:00am on Sunday December 17th, 2011

**Problem**
hour and minutes always display 00:00 and sometime Year is also incorrect

**Input**
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

**functions**

```
public function perfect_date_format($date) {
    $dated = str_replace(array(" ", ":"), "-", $date);
    list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute) = explode("-", $date);
    $niceday = @date("H:ia \o\\n\ l, F jS, Y", mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    return $niceday;
  }
```

Comment: What is the input? And have you tried `strtotime()`?

Comment: can you provide your sample input?

Comment: Show us the input $date string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. The 2nd argument to `explode()` should be `$dated`, rather than `$date`. If you do this, the time is correctly displayed.

```
<?php
function perfect_date_format($date) {
    $dated = str_replace(array(" ", ":"), "-", $date);
    list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute) = explode("-", $dated);
    $niceday = @date("H:ia \o\\n\ l, F jS, Y", mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    return $niceday;
}

echo perfect_date_format('2011-12-17 03:45:00') . "\n";
?>
```

This outputs:

```
03:45am on Saturday, December 17th, 2011
```

BTW: It's safe to remove the [error suppressor operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) (ie. `@`) in the code above. It was simply suppressing errors or warnings caused by the bug identified above. Now that the bug is fixed, the `@` isn't doing anything.

Comment: Nice catch @Asaph, and your answer leaves his original code intact whereas I completely rewrote his function. +1.

Comment: I gave both an upvote, but I would prefer the `strtotime()` method, since it allows for more diversity of input (depending on usage). I'd also probably suggest removing the error suppressor on `date()`.

Comment: I agree that `strtotime()` is a more elegant approach. There are 2 ways to approach questions like this. My approach answers the question "Why is my code not working?" and [@Josh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8545519/166339) answers the question "What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do?". Both are valid and the OP is free to decide which one serves him better.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I also agree about removing the `@` operator. The only purpose it _was_ serving was suppressing errors or warnings caused by the bug I identified in the code. Now that the bug is fixed, it's doing nothing. The error suppressor operator usually just masks problems and I personally avoid it. I left it in the answer because I just wanted to fix the bug and not make any distracting "enhancements".

Comment: I understand that, that wasn't a criticism per se. I don't know I would agree that suggesting removing it would be distracting or whatnot, but your description of why it was there and why it should be left out is part of the overall answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Fair enough. I updated my answer to include a comment about the `@` operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to know hot to correct your code without knowing what you're passing to `perfect_date_format`, but I'll make a wild guess and assume that [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) understands how to parse your `$date`:

```
public function perfect_date_format($date) {
    $time = strtotime($date);
    return date("H:ia \o\\n\ l, F jS, Y", $time);
}
```

If that doesn't work, then please provide the format of the data you're passing as `$date`.